# Inline vector image wraps within table cell

Tags: html, css, svg

Apologies if this has been posted before; there are so many questions relating to inline SVG's I cannot find anything close to this problem.

I have a table, and within the cells there is an inline SVG image.  I notice that the image does not contribute toward the table width, and wraps onto the next line rather than extend the table and display inline as required.

Notice that in the first table, the vector has wrapped onto the next line, rather than flow with the text to fill the screen width.  This must be something real simple, but I am stuck.  I've inspected the element within Firefox/Chrome and see no computed styles that might cause this (e.g. `display:block`).

[image]

[CSS Fiddle available here](https://jsfiddle.net/ehf9no6y/).

```css
td {border:1px solid gray; padding:0.25em; }
td img { max-height:1em; }
td img[src*="svg"] {   }
```

```html
<h2>
Table 1
</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    V
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/CFx.svg" title="" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>


<h2>
Table 2
</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    Stretch out the table width.
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    V
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/CFx.svg" title="" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wrap your content in your table cell in a `div` with `white-space: nowrap;` set on it and it won't wrap, or maybe just put that style on the cell itself

Comment: That's no good.  I need the content to wrap when the screen estate runs out, as text would.

Comment: Seems to be because the image has no defined size. If you add one (say `width:12px`)...it behaves normally. Perhaps because the referenced SVG has an "internal" default size of 100%.

Comment: @Paulie_D hmm interesting.  Not sure if this is a quirk or part of the spec...  <aside> And how do you possibly manage to find the time to answer CSS questions when you're not answering my movie questions...?!?</aside>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is inherent with SVG with *no defined size*.

From the [**SVG2 spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#SizingSVGInCSS)

> The intrinsic dimensions must also be determined from the width and height sizing properties. If either width or height are not specified, the used value is the initial value 'auto'. 'auto' and percentage lengths must not be used to determine an intrinsic width or intrinsic height.

---

> SVG, being inherently scalable, adapts the intrinsic width and intrinsic height to be the width and height of the specified size. Therefore, when specified as a length, the width and height sizing properties of the ‘svg’ element control the intrinsic dimensions of the SVG image and the specified size that is used when placing the SVG image in a host document.

In this case, the referenced SVG has no size specified in it's attributes and so defaults to 100% by 100% (as specified by the browser user agent).

100% width of the table cell means it's forced to a new line.

Simply adding a defined height or width fixes the issue.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

td img {
  max-height: 1em;
}

td img[src*="svg"] {
 height: 1em;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      V
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/CFx.svg" title="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of your img instead of the max-height:

```css
td img {
  height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work.  Any idea what the explanation to this is?  I'm still stumped as to what the underlying reason is...

Comment: See the answer of @Paulie_D!